# Как предотвратить изменение массива после оператора присваивания?

Tags: java

Проще, наверное, объяснить суть вопроса на примере кода:

```
void docode(){
    name1[0]="1";
    name1[1]="1";
    String[] name2 = new String[2];
    System.out.println("1: "+name1[0]+" " + name2[0]);
    name2=getName(name1);
    System.out.println("2: "+name1[0]+" " + name2[0]);
}

String [] getName(String [] somename){
    for (int i=0;i<somename.length;i++){
        somename[i]=somename[i]+"2";
    }
    return somename;
}
```

Выдает результат:

- I/System.out: 1: 1 null
- I/System.out: 2: 12 12

То есть первый массив также изменяется. Как называется эта фича и как наиболее грамотно сделать так, чтобы первый массив не изменялся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы на самом деле в обеих переменных используете ссылку на один и тот же массив, хранящийся в памяти. Естественно, что изменения в его ячейках будут применяться ко всем переменным, которые хранят в себе ссылку на этот массив.

Наверное вам можно попробовать создавать новый массив в методе `getName()` как-то так:

```
String [] getName(String [] somename){
    String[] newArrayInstance = new String[somename.length];
    for (int i=0;i<somename.length;i++){
        newArrayInstance[i]=somename[i]+"2";
    }
    return newArrayInstance;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.